# How to provide dpi/resolution parameter to ZXing Library?

Tags: barcode, zxing

I am trying to use ZXing to create code 128 based 1D barcodes.
I have a requirement to specify the resolution or dpi parameter to generate the 1D barcode.
But I am unable to find this param in the specification?

Is there any way to do so? What am I missing?

If ZXing does not provide this option, is there any other library which provides the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolution has no meaning here, since nothing in the library is concerned with how large you will physically print or display the image. So, a DPI parameter would not make sense. Instead determine the size in pixels that you need and request that.